# I am trying to do a grocery basket application where I want to show an alert and want it to disappear after 2 seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, alert, setinterval, use-effect

If you see below, there is a component named `TimeOut()` in which I am using the `useEffect()` to set the timer for the alert.
And then I'm calling `<TimeOut/>` inside the `handleSubmit()` function inside `if(!name)`. I get an error where I call `<TimeOut/>` "expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression".

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import List from './List'
import Alert from './Alert'

function App() {
const [name, setName]= useState('');
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
const [editID, setEditID] = useState(null);
const [alert, setAlert ] = useState({show: false, msg:'', type:''});

const TimeOut =()=>{
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      // type in message here
      setAlert({show:true, msg:'testing this will be displayed with name', type:''})
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}


const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      // console.log('testing');
      //setAlert({show:true, msg:'Value cannot be empty u idiot', type:''});
      <TimeOut/>
    } else if (name && isEditing) {
      
    } else {
      const newItem = { id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: name };

      setList([...list, newItem]);
      setName('');
    }
    
  };

const forOnChange = (e) =>{
  setName(e.target.value);
}

const showAlert = (show= false, type= '', msg= '')=>{
  setAlert({show:show, msg:msg, type:type})
}


const removeAllItems = ()=>{
  setAlert({show: true, msg: 'List is empty now', type:''});
  setList([]);

}

const removeSpecificItem = (id)=>{
  const newList = list.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
  setList(newList);
}
  return (

    <section className="section-center">
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {alert.show ? <Alert alert={alert} removeAlert={showAlert}/> : null}
        <h4>Grocery basket</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="chickets etc" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
        <button value={name} >{isEditing ? 'Edit' : 'Submit'}</button>

        <button className="clear-btn" onClick={removeAllItems}>Clear all items</button>
      </form>
      {list.length > 0 ? <div className="grocery-container">
          <List items={list} removeSpecificItem={removeSpecificItem}/>
      </div> : null}
      
    </section>

  );
}

export default App
```

Error

```
 Line 31:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 31:8:  'Timeout' is not defined                                               react/jsx-no-undef
```

The error is at

Comment: Can you provide that error here, alongwith code?

Comment: you can remove the `<Timeout />` part and just use your  timeout function there. and i belive what you are looking for is `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`

Comment: Shivam, I have added the error it's at <Timeout />

Comment: Hello @ shashi srinath that worked thank you, but is there a way to use the hook useEffect(), I know if I were to put the useEffect part inside the if statement it'd give me an error since handleSubmit is not a component but is there a way around for that ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      // console.log('testing');
      // <TimeOut/> remove this, you cant use react components here
      setAlert({show:true, msg:'Value cannot be empty u idiot', type:''});

      setTimeout(function () {
          setAlert({show:false, msg:'Value cannot be empty u idiot', type:''});
      }, 2000)

    } else if (name && isEditing) {
      
    } else {
      const newItem = { id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: name };

      setList([...list, newItem]);
      setName('');
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: Hello Shashi that worked thank you, but is there a way to use the hook useEffect(), I know if I were to put the useEffect part inside the if statement it'd give me an error since handleSubmit is not a component but is there a way around for that ?